# Storing, retrieving and searching tags in MySql Database

Tags: php, mysql

I am storing products in a mysql database with tags (now separated with comma's):

```
name       |   price   | tags
-----------------------------------------
cheese     |   6       | yellow, nice
strawberry |   3       | red, fruit
steak      |   5       | red, nice feeling, cold
rice       |   4       | white, china
```

Now, I want to get a list of unique tags, this should return `yellow, nice, red, fruit, nice feeling, cold, white, china`. I'm currently using the method below, but this only checks for unique rows, and not unique tags (comma separated values), so Im getting duplicate values.

```
      $result = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT tags FROM products") or die(mysql_error());

      // check for empty result
      if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
      // looping through all results
      // products node
      while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {               
            // echo out the contents of each row into a table
            if  (!empty($row["tags"])){
            echo  "The tags are: ".$row["tags"] ;
            }
       }
```

Also, I would like to search the database, I've already got that working:

```
       $ref = $tags;
       $query = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE INSTR(tags,'".mysql_real_escape_string($ref)."')>'0'";
       $result = mysql_query($query);
```

How can I get a list of unique tags? and how can I search the tags for multiple values? (so if I search for "nice yellow" it will return cheese.

Comment: For the first question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1838866/428543

Comment: I'm going to wait until the data set is normalised

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting the unique tags using single query with the given structure is not simple. The best thing to do as advised by others is to normalize the data which will help is many operations like search, getting unique data etc.

Now for the first question here is one way of getting it

```
select distinct reverse(substring_index(reverse(substring_index(tags, ',', n.n)), ',', 1)) as tags
from products cross join
     (select 1 as n union all select 2 as n union all select 3 as n union all select 4 as n) n
having tags is not null
```

See the output here http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d9a42/18

Now for search the string pattern is a big issue to do it directly so you may need to split the string in PHP and then use like with AND so to make sure that all the tags that you are searching returns in the result.

With a normalized table structure this would have been far more easy.

Answer (score 1):

You should read about data normalisation. In essence you should store the tags separately. Then every tag would have an ID and every product would have an ID. Products and tags have a many-many relationship, which means you'll have a table linking tags to products.

You should read the following question: [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

Comment: I know this, but I would like to keep it "simple" by having only one database.

Comment: You'll have one database with multiple tables. And your solution is not simple. You have to build some convoluted logic in order to gain functionality that you could get much easier. There is absolutely no point in having a *relational* database if you are not using relations.

Comment: Thats why I quoted simple, I mean a simple table structure. I understand that using a relational database is more reliable.